# Issue with the Browse files button

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload, magento1.9.3

I have a Magento website upgraded from 1.9.2.4 to CE 1.9.3.0 and there is an issue with the file uploads after the upgrade. In CMS page or CMS block if I try to upload an image or file that does not work.

When I click the browse files button nothing happens. I checked for the .swf files in media, removing or adding those files seems to have no effect.

Other websites I have works fine. So I don't think this will be an issue regarding the flash player in the browser.

Does anyone know the solution for this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Try after cleaning var/cache,Flush magento cache

Comment: @RajeshElangovan I have tried it.But it doesnt works.